# CMFCTabCtrl not visible in CDialog

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I've added a CMFCTabCtrl  in a CDialog. But my problem is that it is not visible. This is the code I've used to create the CMFCTabCtrl .

```
m_TabControl.Create (CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D, rectTab, this, 1, CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP , TRUE);
m_TabControl.ShowWindow(TRUE);

m_wnd1.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 100, 100), &m_TabControl, 1);
m_wnd1.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd1.SetWindowText ("Edit 1");

m_wnd2.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 0, 0), &m_TabControl, 2);
m_wnd2.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd2.SetWindowText ("Edit 2");

m_wnd3.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 0, 0), &m_TabControl, 3);
m_wnd3.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd3.SetWindowText ("Edit 3");

m_wnd4.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 0, 0), &m_TabControl, 4);
m_wnd4.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd4.SetWindowText ("Edit 4");


m_TabControl.AddTab (&m_wnd1, "One", 0, TRUE);
m_TabControl.AddTab (&m_wnd2, "Two", 0, FALSE);
m_TabControl.AddTab (&m_wnd3, "Three", 0, FALSE);
m_TabControl.AddTab (&m_wnd4, "Four", 0, FALSE);
```

What am I doing wrong here?/...

Comment: First thing you're doing wrong is that your code has **absolutely no error checking**. That becomes important when it doesn't work like you expect. It tells you precisely where it's failing, and an error code that indicates the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a problem with the code except the following line:

```
m_TabControl.ShowWindow(TRUE);
```

The `ShowWindow()` function should not be necessary and anyway it should take a value of `SW_SHOW`, not `TRUE`, so:

```
m_TabControl.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

But I recommend that you remove this line entirely, it's not necessary.

If you still have a problem after correcting this, post the code you use to define the `RECT` in the `Create()` call.

**EDIT**

Ok, one thing to check. I'm assuming you have a group box or something to define the `RECT`. If so, make sure you set that group box to `Visible: false` in the dialog editor, otherwise it will display on top of your tab control. I just got it working ok by copy/paste of your code and using four `CEdit` controls as `m_wnd1` .. `m_wnd4` (I don't know what you have them declared as).

[image: dialog]

Comment: CRect rectTab;  GetDlgItem(IDC_HOLDER)->GetWindowRect(&rectTab);
ScreenToClient(&rectTab);   Still I have the problem...